# Spring batch: handle subclasses

Tags: spring-batch

Lets suppose that I have class **Event** with and 10 subclasses (**SubEvent1, SubEvent2**... and so on) of class **Event**. I have configured for spring batch **ItemReader**, **ItemProcessor** and **ItemWriter**.

My item processor looks like:

```
ItemProcessor<Event, Outputclass> {
 OutputClass process(Event e) {
   if(e instancof SubEvent1) {
     return processSubEvent1(e);
   } else if(e instanceof SubEvent2) {
     return processSubEvent2(e);
   } else ...
}
```

is it possible to avoid those instanceof and process it by class specific Processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using a combination of:

- [ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html): to process each item with its corresponding `ItemProcessor`
- [SubclassClassifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/classify/SubclassClassifier.html): to classify items according to their subtype.

Hope this helps.